# Will Ubuntu support my machine features?

Tags: wireless, usb, system-installation, hdmi, webcam

I'm looking to download and install the latest version of Ubuntu to replace the current version of Windows I had pre-installed on my machine when bought it.

I have some really neat features on the machine that I really am hoping will still work when I move over to Ubuntu.

Can someone please confirm if the below will still work and, if not, how I can get them to work:

- The USB ports on my machine
- The ethernet or Network work port on the machine
- The HDMI output on the machine
- and finally, the built in webcam

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 4):

### Generic Answer:

In general, all of those things are fairly well supported by popular Linux distributions such as Fedora and Ubuntu.

If you wish to get a good idea of how well Ubuntu will run on your hardware prior to actually trying it, you could just use a search engine like Google or Yahoo to search specific hardware components for known incompatibilities.

If something is going to be an issue out of that list, it will most likely be the HDMI output or webcam. USB ports and wired networking devices do not tend to experience functionality issues with the Linux kernel.

### Best Option (imo):

One route you could go is to try Ubuntu on live CD or USB-drive and test all of these functions out yourself before installing. Instructions for that here:

[Try Ubuntu before you install it - Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install)

Unetbootin is a great way to create a live USB stick from Windows using a downloaded Ubuntu ISO image.

Unetbootin download:

[Unetbootin download for Windows](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/unetbootin-windows-latest.exe)

Ubuntu ISO download page (choose image for your architecture):

[Ubuntu 14.04.1 CD ISO downloads - mirror.anl.gov](http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/CDs/14.04.1/)